# Facebook API: Can I access my page's user's content?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to develop a management tool for my pages and to do that, I need access to the content my users post (as I repost a lot of their content - ex. photos)

It looks like I can get access to all the content that I post, but I can't seem to find any reference to features that'll allow me access to the user's content.

Is this not available in the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the posts for a page at:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[PAGE_NAME_OR_ID]/feed?access_token=...
```

However, you can't filter on this very well. An option that gives you more control is FQL. This query of the [stream](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/) table should get you started with posts by others.

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, message, attachment, permalink FROM stream
  WHERE source_id = [PAGE_ID] AND filter_key = 'others'
```

If a user has set their post to private, it won't be returned by this call. You also need to be aware of the limits of the `stream` table: It only returns up to 50 posts in the last 30 days. If you want more, you have to use a LIMIT clause to page through your results.

Comment: Excellent. That's even better than I had hoped :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am developing Facebook application from last two years as per my experience you can't get any users information and using **Page Signed request** you can get **userid,isowner,timezone and isLiked**  only..